# Passing one value using 2 forms to multiple php files

Tags: html, forms, header, export-to-csv

I have a user input for fields 'from' and 'to' which has to be submitted to two different php files which does the export of mysql table to csv file and opens it in a new window for downloading. 
As I have 2 tables and 2 CSV files to be downloaded by the user, I am having this form to pass values to 2 php files which does the export.

Below code has 2 forms and 2 phps, only the first one is working fine. The second form is unable to access the $_POST array.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>EXPORT INVOICE </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
      function runscript()
      {
        document.f1.submit();
        document.f2.submit();
      }
    </SCRIPT>

    </head>

    <body>

        <form name="f1" method="post" action="export-tst-with-header.php" target="_blank">

        <br>
        <span class="sty2">Enter to export From Invoice No.:</span> <input type="text" size='10' maxlength='10' name="finv">

        <span class="sty2">To Invoice No:</span>&nbsp; <input type="text"  size='10' maxlength='10' name="tinv">
        </form>

            <form name="f2" method="post" action="export-tst-with-header2.php" target="_blank">
            </form>

        <input type="button" value="Export" onClick="runscript()">


    </body>
    </html>
```

Below is the first EXPORT file to convert mysql table to csv file, which is working fine, the second file is also same but only the table exported is different, which is not working:

```
    <?php

    //echo "Exporting file - process"."<br><br>";

    $dbservertype='mysql';
    $servername='localhost';
    $dbusername='aab';
    $dbpassword='aabs';
    $dbname='aab';

    ////////////////////////////////////////
    ////// DONOT EDIT BELOW  /////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////
    connecttodb($servername,$dbname,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
    function connecttodb($servername,$dbname,$dbuser,$dbpassword)
    {
    global $link;
    $link=mysql_connect ("$servername","$dbuser","$dbpassword");
    if(!$link){die("Could not connect to MySQL");}
    mysql_select_db("$dbname",$link) or die ("could not open db".mysql_error());
    }
    //////// End of connecting to database ////////
    $from=$_POST['finv'];
    $to=$_POST['tinv'];

    //echo $_POST['action'];

    //if ($_POST['action'] == 'download')
    //{

        header("Content-type: application/csv");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=downloadinv.csv");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");



    $query = "SELECT * FROM INVHDR WHERE Invno between $from AND $to";

    $export = mysql_query ($query ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );

    $fields = mysql_num_fields ( $export );

    for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
    {
        $header .= mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) . "\t";

    }

    while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) )
    {
        $line = '';
        foreach( $row as $value )
        {                                            
            if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
            {
                $value = "\t";
            }
            else
            {
                $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
                $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
            }
            $line .= $value;
        }
        $data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
    }
    $data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );

    if ( $data == "" )
    {
        $data = "\n(0) Records Found!\n";                        
    }

    mysql_query("UPDATE INVHDR SET Export=1 WHERE Invno between $from AND $to");

    print "$header\n$data";


    //}
    exit();
    php?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the $_POST['finv'] and $_POST['tinv'] to the second php page.
Either you store them inside a $_SESSION variables (and recuperate them from $_SESSION['finv'] and $_SESSION['tinv'] in the second page or you create a hidden field and repost them.

Comment: I added hidden field for the second form, it is not working, my code:   <form name="f2" method="post" action="export-tst-with-header2.php" target="_blank">
  <input type="hidden" size='10' maxlength='10' name="finv">
  <input type="hidden"  size='10' maxlength='10' name="tinv">
  </form>

Comment: you need to itialize it the value of $_POST['tinv']
I don't encourage this solution if you use a SESSION it will be easier

Comment: Thankyou, session is working fine. just added this:session_start();
  if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
  $_SESSION['finv'] = $_POST['finv'];
  $_SESSION['tinv'] = $_POST['tinv'];
  }